# gdb error: No symbol "tmp" in current context

Tags: gdb

I am debugging C code with gdb and I get an error I don't understand.

My code has this line:

```
101       tmp[0] = path[0];
```

after executing the line I want to print `tmp` (which is `char*`) I get this message:

```
(gdb) out tmp
No symbol "tmp" in current context.
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Dudy.

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with `-O0` and `-g`

Answer (score 4):

It most likely was optimized away, or else compiled without debug symbols.

Try compiling with `-O0` to remove optimizations and with `-g` to have debug symbols.